# Creating shapefile from OS MasterMap data using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, united-kingdom, os-mastermap

How do I create a shapefile from **[OS MasterMap](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/index.html)** data in ArcMap 10?

I have tiles from the Ordnance Survey Site and would like to create a topomap from the existing tiles.

These tiles contains the data I require for the creation of the shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a translator to convert from the Ordnance Survey GML 2.1.2 to an ESRI Shapefile. Unfortunately many of the native GML translators fail to work with the Ordnance Survey OS MasterMap Topography data because of the nested structure of the data.

The list below are the ones I know about and will all work for converting Ordnance Survey GML files. There may be some others.

Some options are

- ESRI Productivity Suite
- ESRI Interopability Extension
- Astun Technology GML Loader (this does convert to shapefiles)
- Lutra Consulting have one which is used with QGIS -
  http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/resources/ostranslator
- FME
- Dotted Eyes InterpOSe
- I think Cadcorp can read it natively

There are others that will load into a database like

- Snowflake GO LOADER
- Dotted Eyes SuperpOSe
- Astun Technology GML Loader
- FME

Standard GDAL/OGR2OGR will not correctly read all the features but several of the above use OGR2OGR as a base.

---

If it is a road network you are after you might be using the wrong dataset.

You might be intersted to look at OS MasterMap Intergrated Transport Network (ITN). This is a GML dataset containing all the link and nodes plus Road Routing Information for GB.

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/itn-layer/index.html

And some information here on how to use it for routing.

http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/support/products/os-mastermap/routing-with-integrated-transport-network-data.html

---

If you have further questions you might want to contact Ordnance Survey Customer Service team.